# hadoop Web UI localhost:50070 can not open

Tags: hadoop3

> Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 
> Hadoop 3.3.1

I try to set up hadoop pseudo distributed mode referring to one network tutorial.and follow below steps.
**Step 1:setting Hadoop**
1.add below code to /etc/profile.

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/hadoop/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME 
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native 
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin 
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
```

2.in $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh,set

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_261
```

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>fs.default.name </name>
      <value> hdfs://localhost:9000 </value> 
   </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
      <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoop/pseudo/hdfs/namenode</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.data.dir</name> 
      <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoop/pseudo/hdfs/datanode</value> 
   </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value> 
   </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
   <property> 
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

**Step 2:Verify Hadoop**
1.$ hdfs namenode -format
2.

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id hadoop@ubuntu
cd ~/hadoop/sbin
start-dfs.sh
```

3.start-yarn.sh 
4.open http://localhost:50070/ in firefox on local machine.

> Unable to connect
> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:50070.
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
> If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

[image]

5.open http://localhost:8088/ in firefox ,returns the same error of port 50070.

when I run jps command,it returns

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~/hadoop/sbin$ jps
32501 DataNode
32377 NameNode
32682 SecondaryNameNode
32876 Jps
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Hadoop 3.0.0 - Alpha 1 there was a Change in the port configuration:

http://localhost:50070

was moved to

http://localhost:9870

see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-9427